# Using DependencyProperty in a Control properly disposable

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a lot of custom TextBlocks with text that should fit content of parent container. 
Following solution works but it is rather slow and I believe creates memory leaks. Is there better way to use OnMyDataChanged? Will it be properly disposed with this type of Dependency property?

```
public class TrimmingTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    FrameworkElement _container; //StackPanel which holds this TextBlock
    public string LongText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LongTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LongTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LongTextProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("LongText", typeof(string), typeof(TrimmingTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(OnMyDataChanged));

    static void OnMyDataChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {           
        TrimmingTextBlock tb = obj as TrimmingTextBlock;            
        tb.ShortenIt(); //shorten text when text is changed
    }

    private void ShortenIt()
    {
        string mytext = LongText;
        _container = (FrameworkElement)this.Parent;        
        double _containerwidth = _container.ActualWidth;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //do a CPU intensitive text manupulation so it fits _container
            ...
            //
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.Text = mytext;
            }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
        });
    }

    public TrimmingTextBlock()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(container_SizeChanged);
    }
    void container_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       ShortenIt(); //if container size changed (window resized) shorten the text again
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not using `TextTrimming` DP already exposed by TextBlock?

Comment: @RohitVats I just called it text trimming but method does more text manupilation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to be absolutely sure that `+=` clause will not cause a memory leak, you can replace it with the following code:

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    this.ShortenIt();
}
```

so delegate invocation list of that event will be empty.

Second - I think that you should to review your **CPU intensitive text manupulation** in order to improve its performance, so that you will put all logic inside one method, that will be executed on the **UI** thread, because [SizeChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) can occur many times during the run-time, and per each event you want to create a [TPL Task](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdd460717(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=winAU5jhNce6ygOPvYLgAQ&usg=AFQjCNE0Nat-wtEZsjVxU3pox9YIZ4vkvQ&sig2=xHp7Bxcn95VOB3l8Utxqng&bvm=bv.70810081,d.bGQ), (which can execute on the UI thread), and this is where your main overhead may come from.